# How to write to a range of cells based on a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 variables. For example:
apple=3, orange=2

I want to write to a range of cells the following text:
(A1): Number of apples 1
(A2): Number of apples 2
(A3): Number of apples 3
(A4): Number of oranges 1
(A5): Number of oranges 2

Right now this is what I have in my code:

```
Dim apple As Integer
apple = InputBox("Please enter number of apples")
Range ("A1").Value = "Number of apples" & apple

Dim orange As Integer
orange = InputBox("Please enter number of oranges")
Range ("A2").Value = "Number of oranges" & orange
```

I think I need to create a loop to get the desired result. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should try something and share with us, What didn't work, which error do you get ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add loop to add apples and oranges. Try below codes-

```
Sub FillFruits()
Dim apple As Integer, orange As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
apple = InputBox("Please enter number of apples")
orange = InputBox("Please enter number of oranges")

    For i = 1 To apple
        Cells(lRow, 1) = "Apple " & i
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next i

    For j = 1 To orange
        Cells(lRow, 1) = "Orange " & j
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I have a question, what does 1Row and x1Up do? I think 1Row is a variable, but what is End(x1Up)?

Comment: @Belle `lRow` means last row now that are not empty. Last non empty row in column1. `xlup` identify last data entry cell from bottom to top in a column.